# Unauthorized error while passing access_token to the REST Call

Tags: spring, oauth, access-token, okta

I have obtained the access token using appropriate endpoint using okta. using the obtained access token i am trying to make a REST call by passing access token as Authorization Header type Bearer. but getting 401 unauthorized error with the following error message

"Full authentication is required to access this resource"

AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "fXMuUOUo31nNlbnnjn64019h3JP-s6VZEOV4VGW1";

static final String CLIENT_ID = "0oaz4m4njwGDMqXB1356";

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer.inMemory()
        .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
        .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
        .authorizedGrantTypes(new String[] { "password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code" })
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey("as466gf");
    return converter;
}

/**
 * Bean for Token Servers Primary is added as there are three token services in the classpath
 *
 * @return DefaultTokenServices Default Token Service
 */
@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    return defaultTokenServices;
}

}
```

ResourceServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/authenticate/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/greet/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/getRefreshedTokens/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("ResourceId");
}

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

/**
 * OAuth ignores the configuration below
 * 
 * @See ResourceServerConfig to control Authorization
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/authenticate/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/greet/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/getRefreshedTokens/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
}

}
```

Comment: Could you paste your code and configuration, please?

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa sorry i was not much aware of Configuration at that time. later i made the above configuration changes but still my problem is not solved.